# Specifying a return type for a protocol function in the declaration of a class that conforms to that protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift 3, and I'd like to accomplish something I'm not sure is possible. My backend has a couple of different endpoints for different content types which pages the response in different ways etc. I am trying to create a generic protocol that can be implemented for every content type.

```
protocol DynamicContentFetcher {
    func content() -> MutableObservableArray<Any>
    func getNext()
    func refresh()
}
```

One of those instances is AdSearch.

```
class AdSearch: DynamicContentFetcher {
    var results = MutableObservableArray<DynamicAd>([])
    func content() -> MutableObservableArray<Any> {
        return results
    }
```

That `return` does not compile with error `Cannot convert return expression of type MutableObservableArray<DynamicAd> to return type 'MutableObservableArray<Any>`, which makes sense.

What would be nice, was if I could init my classes conforming to `DynamicContentFetcher` like `AdSearch<DynamicAd>` and use that value in <> to do `func content() -> MutableObservableArray<#Specified Type#>` in the protocol. Is this possible with Swift?

`MutableObservableArray` is a class from the [Bond](https://github.com/ReactiveKit/Bond) framework, a reactive programming pod.

Comment: Generics are not covariant in Swift; that's where the error comes from: `MOA<DynamicAd>` is not a subtype of `MOA<Any>`. Make the type parameter explicit (as shown in the answer by dfri) and all is good. (Side not: you picked a bad title; it does not tell us anything about your question.)

Comment: @Raphael Sorry about the title, english is not my first language and I had a hard time describing what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `associatedtype` in your protocol, and use this as the typeholder in the return type of `content()` in you protocol:

```
struct MutableObservableArray<T> {}

protocol DynamicContentFetcher {
    associatedtype T
    func content() -> MutableObservableArray<T>
    //func getNext()
    //func refresh()
}

struct DynamicAd {}

class AdSearch: DynamicContentFetcher {
    var results = MutableObservableArray<DynamicAd>()
    func content() -> MutableObservableArray<DynamicAd> {
        return results
    }
}
```

---

> What would be nice, was if I could init my classes conforming to
>   `DynamicContentFetcher` like `AdSearch<DynamicAd>` and use that value in
>   `<>` to do `func content() -> MutableObservableArray<#Specified Type#>` in
>   the protocol.

You might want to let the `AdSeach` class be generic, holding a generic typeholder which is used to specify (below, implicitly by inference) the `typealias` for the `associatedtype` of the `DynamicContentFetcher` protocol.

```
class AdSearch<U>: DynamicContentFetcher {
    // typealias T = U // infered
    var results = MutableObservableArray<U>()
    func content() -> MutableObservableArray<U> {
        return results
    }
}

struct DynamicAd {}
let dynamicAdSearch = AdSearch<DynamicAd>()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make it so I can define without specifying the Type as well? In the model that defines AdSearch I´d like to have a `var contentFetcher: DynamicContentFetcher<Any/DynamicContent/nothing>` but this either gives me "Protocol can only be used as a generic contains because it has Self or at type requirements" if I don't specify it, or "Cannot specialise non-generic type" if I specify it.

Comment: It's kind of cool that the Swift compiler can figure out which type `AdSearch` uses for `T`, but I think for clarity adding `typealias T = DynamicAd` is a good idea.

Comment: @OscarApeland You can declare something like this: `func contentFetcher<U: DynamicContentFetcher>() -> U where U.T: DynamicContent {...}`. How you instantiate a return value, I don't know. :D

Comment: @Raphael thanks for yours comments. Regarding the explicit `typealias`, I believe it's a matter of taste (I prefer myself to rely solely on inferrence, generally in Swift, when possible), but good nonetheless that this explicit alternative is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @OscarApeland updated w.r.t. the updates in your question (-> made `AdSearch` generic).